# View the list of favorite users

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I use Laravel 5.8 in my project.

I have this model:

User

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;
    use cms\Presenters\UserPresenter;

    public static $roles = [];
    public $dates = ['last_activity'];

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'surname', 'email', 'email_verified_at', 'password', 'counter', 'url_address', 'isCompany', 'isMailing', 'content'];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }

    public function mainRole()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Role');
    }

    public function favourites()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Likeable');
    }
}
```

Likeable

```
class Likeable extends Model
{
    protected $quarded = [];
    protected $fillable = ['likeable_id', 'user_id'];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

My migration:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('surname', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('email', 120)->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');]
            $table->char('isMailing', 1)->default(0);
            $table->text('content')->nullable();
            .....
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
        });
    }
Schema::create('likeables', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('likeable_id');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
        });
```

I have a problem with displaying the list of users who have been added to the user's favorite list.

When I make this:

```
dd($request->user()->favourites);
```

I get this result:

```
Collection {#1031 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Likeable {#1032 ▶}
  ]
}
```

And I need to get a user (likeables. Likeable_id = users.id)

How to do it? How do I fix my code to receive such a result?

Answer (score 1):

If you want access to favourites as a parameter, you need to add favourites in appends array inside User model
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

```
private $appends = ['favourites'];
```

Also you need to create a mutator (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) for automatically fill this variable:

```
function getFavouritesAttribute(){
    return $this->favourites()->get();
}
```

After this you can just call:

```
$request->user()->favourites
```

And you recive full user favorites list

Also please try to change

```
public function favourites()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Likeable');
}
```

To:

```
public function favourites(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Likeable', 'likeable_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: It's not working. I have this result: Collection {#995 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Likeable {#996 ▼
      #quarded: []
      #fillable: array:2 [▶]
      ...
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Updated answer,please try to change favourites

Comment: Thank you. Now I have: Collection {#996 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Likeable {#997 ▶}
    1 => Likeable {#998 ▶}
  ]
} (2 result). I have 2 records in the database - every other user. The script should report 1 result

Comment: Try to chenge hasMany to hasOne in favorites method. This should help

Comment: Now 1 have one result. But I have this: Likeable {#1031 ▼
  #quarded: []

  ....
} - not User :(

Comment: Try dd($request->user()) you get user info with favorite field inside

Comment: I haven't favorites. Relations etc is empty

Comment: User {#608 ▼
  +dates: array:1 [▶]
  +appends: array:1 [▼
    0 => "favorites"
  ]

Comment: Use var_dump($request->user()) instead dd to receive full dump of class with relations

Comment: I haven't relations with likables :(

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, made a mistake in method name in main answer,
wrote 'favorites' instead 'favourites', edited now, please fix it in code and all definitely should work fine

Comment: It's not help. Now I have this code: Collection {#1032 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Likeable {#1033 ▼
      #fillable: array:2 [▶]
      #table: "likeables"
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:3 [▶]
      #original: array:3 [▶]
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }